# Matchear una serie de palabras usando expresiones regulares excepto si está precedida por una palabra específica

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript, outlook

Estoy tratando de hacer un script con VB para armar unas rules de Outlook para que me filtren unos mails dependiendo de si se cumple determinada condición y los envíe a una determinada carpeta.

La expresión regular que formulé es esta:
`[uU][aA][tT]+(01|1)|\b([uU][aA][tT])\b` 
Y este es el código completo del script:

```
Sub detectarTarea(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim MailDest As Outlook.Folder
    Dim esTarea As Boolean

    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set filterUs = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    filterUs.Global = True
    filterUs.Pattern = "([uU][sS][-](?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?"
    
    Set filterRbf = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    filterRbf.Global = True
    filterRbf.Pattern = "([rR][bB][fF][-](?=\.\d|\d)(?:\d+)?(?:\.?\d*))(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?"
    
    Set filterUat01 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    filterUat01.Global = True
    filterUat01.Pattern = "[uU][aA][tT]+(01|1)|(\b)[uU][aA][tT](\b)"
    
    Set filterSit02 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    filterSit02.Global = True
    filterSit02.Pattern = "[sS][iI][tT]+(02|2)"
    
    Set MailDest = ns.Folders("micorreo@correo.com").Folders("Mis tareas")
    Set MailDestUat01 = ns.Folders("micorreo@correo.com").Folders("Mis tareas").Folders("UAT01")
    Set MailDestSit02 = ns.Folders("micorreo@correo.com").Folders("Mis tareas").Folders("SIT02")
    
    
    If filterUs.Test(Item.Subject) Then
        esTarea = True
    ElseIf filterUs.Test(Item.Body) Then
        esTarea = True
    ElseIf filterRbf.Test(Item.Subject) Then
        esTarea = True
    ElseIf filterRbf.Test(Item.Body) Then
        esTarea = True
    Else
        esTarea = False
    End If
    
    If esTarea = True And filterUat01.Test(Item.Subject) Then
        Item.Move MailDestUat01
    ElseIf esTarea = True And filterUat01.Test(Item.Body) Then
        Item.Move MailDestUat01
    ElseIf esTarea = True And filterSit02.Test(Item.Subject) Then
        Item.Move MailDestSit02
    ElseIf esTarea = True And filterSit02.Test(Item.Body) Then
        Item.Move MailDestSit02
    ElseIf esTarea = True Then
        Item.Move MailDest
    End If
End Sub
```

Actualmente el Script detecta si es una tarea o no dependiendo de si contiene alguna palabra que comience con RBF- o US-, en dado caso, pasa a detectar a qué carpeta debe de mover el mail dependiendo de si dice (UAT01, UAT1, UAT) -> Carpeta UAT01, o (SIT02, SIT2) -> Carpeta SIT02.

El asunto está en que también matchea si es que aparece la frase "Equipo UAT" que es el grupo de mails al que pertenezco. El problema es que si envían un mail al mismo grupo de mails, pero este no es un mail que corresponda filtrar a la carpeta UAT, me lo filtra igual ya que obedece la regla antes mencionada: contiene la palabra UAT sola.

Un ejemplo de mail donde se genera el conflicto es este:

```
Se ha confirmado el impacto ambiente SIT02.

Gracias Equipo UAT.
```

En este caso tendría que enviar el mail a la carpeta SIT02, pero no, la envía a UAT01 ya que primero está matcheando UAT solo.

Estuve buscando por horas y no encuentro forma de omitir esa frase del filtrado. ¿Alguien podría darme una mano?

Comment: `re.Global = True` se usa para obtener más de 1 coincidencia. En este caso no hace falta... y normalmente nunca es necesario cuando se usa `RegExp.Test()`

Answer (score 0):

Para que coincida con un patrón, excepto si está precedida por `"Equipo"`:

```
Set filterUat01 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
filterUat01.IgnoreCase = True
filterUat01.MultiLine = True
filterUat01.Pattern = "(?:^|\b(?!Equipo)\w+)\W*UAT(?:0?1)?\b"
```

Como verás, es algo entreverado, principalmente porque VBScript es algo limitado. En particular, porque no implementa inspecciones hacia atrás.

Entonces, para resolverlo lo que hago es pararme en **la palabra anterior** (o el inicio de la línea `^`), asegurando de que *no esté seguido* por `Equipo` con la inspección hacia adelante `(?!Equipo)`, y luego consumo la palabra entera con `\w+`. Esta `\w+` lo que hace es coincidir con la palabra previa a `UAT`, siempre que no sea `Equipo`.